# When we use OData and Mapster in EF Core with customDTO. OdataQueryOptions is getting overridden

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, odata, mapster

What we want to do is that the tenant attached to the carrier does not come under all circumstances.

I have OData and Mapster in my .NET Core project. I want to convert the OData query to dto with `ProjectToType`, which I also use in mapster. However, `ProjectToType` is overriding the EF Core query generated by the OData query. And it goes to the database with a big SQL query. It tries to handle all transactions in in-memory, but I only want to get one property from the database. I have shared the details of my project and the results I expected below.

Controller:

```
[Area("odata")]
[Route("[area]/v{v:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class CargoCarriersODataController : ODataControllerBase
{
    private readonly IGenericReadRepository<Guid> _genericReadRepository;

    public CargoCarriersODataController(IGenericReadRepository<Guid> genericReadRepository)
    {
        _genericReadRepository = genericReadRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IQueryable<CargoCarriersODataDto>))]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<CargoCarriersODataDto>>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Carrier> opts)
    {
        var carriers = _genericReadRepository.GetAll<Carrier>();
        opts.ApplyTo(carriers);
        return Ok(carriers.ProjectToType<CargoCarriersODataDto>());
    }
}
```

DTO classes:

```
public class CargoCarriersODataDto
{
    public int RId { get; set; }
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public TenantDto Tenant { get; set; }
    public Guid CargoCarrierId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EnabledLogoUrl { get; set; }
    public string DisabledLogoUrl { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool DoesSupportSameDayShipment { get; set; }
}

public class TenantDto
{
    public int RId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }
}

public class CargoCarriersDtoCustomMap : IRegister
{
    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.ForType<Carrier, CargoCarriersODataDto>()
            .Map(dest => dest.RId, src => src.RId)
            .Map(dest => dest.TenantId, src => src.TenantId)
            .Map(dest => dest.CargoCarrierId, src => src.CargoCarrierId)
            .Map(dest => dest.Name, src => src.Name)
            .Map(dest => dest.EnabledLogoUrl, src => src.EnabledLogoUrl)
            .Map(dest => dest.DisabledLogoUrl, src => src.DisabledLogoUrl)
            .Map(dest => dest.IsEnabled, src => src.IsEnabled)
            .Map(dest => dest.DoesSupportSameDayShipment, src => src.DoesSupportSameDayShipment)
            .Map(dest => dest.Tenant, src => src.Tenant);
    }
}

public class TenantDtoCustomMap : IRegister
{
    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.ForType<Tenant, TenantDto>()
        .Ignore(dest => dest, src => new TenantDto
        {
            RId = src.RId,
            CompanyEmail = src.CompanyEmail,
            Name = src.Name,
            CompanyName = src.CompanyName,
            PhoneNumber = src.PhoneNumber
        });
    }
}
```

The query we expect when we send it as

```
http://localhost:8076/odata/v1/CargoCarriersOData?$select=name
```

```
SELECT N'Name' AS [Name], [c].[Name] AS [Value], N'Id' AS [Name], [c].[Id] AS [Value]
FROM [Carriers] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[DeletedAt] IS NULL AND ([c].[TenantId] = 'fa9f75b5-c518-40af-8731-020815551704')
```

but the query generated by OData

```
SELECT [c].[RId], [c].[TenantId], CAST(0 AS bit), [t0].[RId], [t0].[Name], [t0].[CompanyName], [t0].[PhoneNumber], [t0].[CompanyEmail], [c].[CargoCarrierId], [c].[Name], [c].[EnabledLogoUrl], [c].[DisabledLogoUrl], [c].[IsEnabled], [c].[DoesSupportSameDayShipment]
FROM [Carriers] AS [c]
INNER JOIN (
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[CompanyEmail], [t].[CompanyName], [t].[CreatedAt], [t].[CreatedBy], [t].[DeletedAt], [t].[DeletedBy], [t].[Name], [t].[PhoneNumber], [t].[RId], [t].[StorageAccountConnectionString], [t].[UpdatedAt], [t].[UpdatedBy], [t].[Version]
FROM [Tenants] AS [t]
WHERE [t].[DeletedAt] IS NULL
) AS [t0] ON [c].[TenantId] = [t0].[Id]
WHERE [c].[DeletedAt] IS NULL AND ([c].[TenantId] = 'fa9f75b5-c518-40af-8731-020815551704')
```

I am using

- .NET Core 3.1
- OData 7.5.7
- Mapster 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. `opts.ApplyTo(..)` reutrns `IQueryable`, but your code ignores result
2. `ApplyTo` applied to `IQueryable<Carrier>` but should be applied to  `IQueryable<CargoCarriersODataDto>`

```cs
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IQueryable<CargoCarriersODataDto>))]
public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<CargoCarriersODataDto>>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Carrier> opts)
{
    var carriers = _genericReadRepository.GetAll<Carrier>();
    var projected = carriers.ProjectToType<CargoCarriersODataDto>();
    projected = opts.ApplyTo(projected);
    return Ok(projected);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the result did not change